# Javascript Koans - About Objects - how does this function work in #3

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am working on the Javascript Koans - About Objects - Question #3
and having trouble understand how the battleCry function within the Object works.
Specifically the part

> Array(noOfBrains + 1).join(" " + this.mastermind)

When the function was called with the parameter (4), doesn't it mean (noOfBrains) = 4. Thus

> Array( 4 + 1 ).join(" " + this.mastermind)

Does it mean that this *array* has 5 undefined properties?
Then it's joined by a space and the mastermind name "Brain".
I don't get how the correct answer below produces 4 x "Brain", there's no loop function there right? And how come it's not 5 x "Brain" ?

Below is the code with the correct answer.

```
it("should know properties that are functions act like methods",function () {
var megalomaniac = {
  mastermind : "Brain",
  henchman: "Pinky",
  battleCry: function (noOfBrains) {
    return "They are " + this.henchman + " and the" +
      Array(noOfBrains + 1).join(" " + this.mastermind);
  }
};

var battleCry = megalomaniac.battleCry(4);
expect("They are Pinky and the Brain Brain Brain Brain").toMatch(battleCry);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Array()` constructor is designed to be callable without `new` so that it returns the same sort of thing it would if it *were* called with `new` — that is, a new array instance with the given number of uninitialized elements.

The `.join()` function converts each array element to a string according to some well-defined rules, and then return a concatenated string with the argument to `.join()` between each string from the array elements.

Elements that are `undefined` are converted to empty strings. Thus, your code builds an array with 5 empty (`undefined`) elements, and joins them together with that expression, a space followed by `this.mastermind` (`"Pinky"`) as the separator. Between five empty strings there'll be four separators.